# fixed bar over scrollable background: CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

As the title says I am hoping to have fixed bar, off centre, with a background that scrolls. I have included my code so far, as of now i can either have the bar on the surface but fixed to the background, or the bar beneath the image, but fixed to the window as I would like. I can't figure out how to keep the "contentBox" on the surface of the window. Thank you for your help (and sorry for the messy code, this is my first go at CSS)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ height:100%}
#bg {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:grey;
    top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#bg img {
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin-left:10%;
min-width:80%;
height:100%;
}
#contentBox
 {
   position:top;
   left:0;
   margin-top:25%;
   height:30%;
   max-width:90%;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   opacity:0.6;
   filter:alpha(opacity=60);
 }
#contentBox:hover
 {
   position:top;
   left:0;
   margin-top:25%;
   height:30%;
   max-width:90%;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   opacity:0.9;
   filter:alpha(opacity=90);
 }
#linkCloud
 {
   float:left;
   min-width:11%;
   min-height:100%;
   background-color:blue;
   opacity:0.9;
   filter:alpha(opacity=90);
 }
#feed
 {
   float:right;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   min-height:100%;
   min-width:10%;
   background-color:red;
   opacity:0.9;
   filter:alpha(opacity=90);
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="bg">
      <img src="/home/samzors/Desktop/Gimp/skull.jpg" alt="">

      <div id="feed">
         <p>hello world</p>
      </div>

      <div id="contentBox">

         <div id="linkCloud">
           <p>hello world</p>
         </div>

     </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you right, I believe what you want is a bar with a **fixed** position at the top of the viewport. This is done with **position: fixed**, like so:

```
<style>
    #contentBox {
        position: fixed;
        left: ; /* some distance from left side of screen */
        top: ; /* some distance from top of screen */
    }
    ...
</style>

...

<body>
    <div id="contentBox">content</div>
    <div id="bg"> rest of your content </div>
</body>
```

You will probably also want to add a margin-top property for #bg that offsets it from the top of screen at least as much as #contentBox is tall.

One additional note -- if you want to use a psuedo-class like :hover, you do not need to set each of the properties again, only the ones that are being changed. So for instance in #contentBox:hover you would only need:

```
#contentBox:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter = alpha(opacity = 90);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The problem still exists though, when the position is fixed, you can not see the bar, but it is fixed and the background is scroll able (you can see the link cloud which is in the bar, just not the bar itself) but when on top you can see the bar, but the position is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, it is a bit of a hack however.

First in the html code I separated the bg (background) class from the contentBox class, as suggested by cmw. since fixing the content box hid the box from view here is where the hack came in: making a second div class, "content", that was a subset of contentBox, I was then able to display this box fixed to the screen with the bg class remaining scrollable.